# Moving a flex item from inside a column of items to its own column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have a flex container with three children with `flex-direction: column`, and I want to move the middle child to the right while keeping the first and third child to the left, how would I do that?

Is flexbox even the correct approach or is something else more appropriate?

This is my attempt:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  @media (max-width: 840px) {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
}
.red,
.green,
.blue {
  width: 50%;
  @media (max-width: 840px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/dye/pen/mOeZma

It's close, but not quite there. When green div moves to the right, there's a big gap between red and blue.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: best way i think is to position the third child `absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying I like flexbox. It can take some time to get your head around all the little things it can do.

If I understood the question I think this does what you want (you'll need to press the full-screen button to see it in all it's glory, as I included the less that 840px stuff).

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px
}
.blue,
.green,
.red {
  width: 50vw
}
.red {
  height: 100px;
  background: red
}
.green {
  height: 200px;
  order: 1;
  background: green
}
.blue {
  background: #00f;
  height: 300px
}
@media (max-width: 840px) {
  .container {
    height: auto
  }
  .blue,
  .green,
  .red {
    width: 100vw
  }
  .green {
    order: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

I've manually set the height of the container to trigger the wrapping, and I've giving green a positive order so it's at the bottom of the list. Though when it's small and all in one column I've taken the order away so it is in the middle again.

I hope this helps, and never give up on flexbox ;-)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I love flexbox, too, but I'm terrible at reasoning through complexities like this.

Comment: Is there a way to use your method if the left side will have a dynamic height? Specifically, blue child (bottom left) will change as content is added to it. Do I just change the height of the container as blue grows? Without specifying the height, green stays below blue. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Flexbox doesn't have the flexibility that you want especially when you are building a dynamic.

If this is static

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.holder {
  width: 50%;
}
.holder .red, .holder .blue {
  width: 100%;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue {
  width: 50%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

So, the answer might be in **javascript**.

I prefer to just use masonry.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Instructions are straight-forward. It is easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.green{
  float: right;
}
.red,
.green,
.blue {
  width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
   

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Ive removed the `flex` box and `float` it instead. much simpler i think

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these directly answer your question but may be of use to those in the future who find their way here with similar questions..

**1**. On the possibility that you are wanting to keep the two left blocks the same height as the right (green) here is how you could do that (i added two wrappers, additional code)

- note: the jquery is just for demonstration purposes

```js
// the jquery is just to adjust height for vertical flex demonstration
$('adjustorator').click(function() {var heights = Array(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 450, 500);var height = heights[Math.floor(Math.random()*heights.length)]; $('.green').css('height', height)});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
}

.red, .blue, .green {
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 400px;
}

// scaffolding below, ignore
body { position: relative; }
adjustorator { display: flex; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%);  padding: 4px 8px 2px 8px; font-variant: small-caps;  color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1); background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1); border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;}
adjustorator:hover { background-color: hsla(200, 40%, 40%, 1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- scaffolding, ignore -->
<adjustorator>adjust height</adjustorator>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/42qzzhdu/

**2** I'll also leave my original (non-) answer for those who come here in the future, looking for a solution to a similar question

`align-self: flex-end;` added to .green

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/42qzzhdu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add order property to .green class.

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    order: 1;
 }
```

and you can order all the elements as well.

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    order: 1;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    order: 3;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    order: 2;
}
```

Comment: by default everything is order 0, meaning it will render in the order it is in the page. So giving only one item order 1 will more it to the end :-)

Comment: Absolutely, default value of order is 0 (y)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just should turn on flex for container only for max width: 840px? For higher resolutions you can make container display block and float first and third div to left and second to right, that's all.

```
.container {
    @media (max-width: 840px) {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
    }
}

.red,
.green,
.blue {
    width: 50%;
    @media (max-width: 840px) {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    @media (min-width: 841px) {
        float: left;
    }
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    @media (min-width: 841px) {
        float: right;
    }
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    @media (min-width: 841px) {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGjegM